# How to convert hex data to byte data in ECL?

Tags: hpcc-ecl, hpcc

I am working on a code in ECL and trying to convert hex data into byte data. I am using the following line of code for this:

```
hex_data := Std.Str.ToHexPairs((>DATA<)ds.contents);
d1:=Std.Str.FromHexPairs(hex_data);
```

But when I uncomment the second line, I get an error. Can someone please guide me on how to correctly convert hex data to byte data in ECL?

This is the entire code am working on:

```
IMPORT PYTHON3 AS PYTHON;
IMPORT Std;


// Note that the filesize doesn't really show up anywhere, even though we sprayed with FILENAME,FILESIZE.
// It is embedded in the length of the contents field.
myRec := RECORD
 STRING filename;
 DATA contents;
END;
// I had sprayed a list of files (2) to 'thor::img.flat'.  Make sure you run both the spray and the job on the thor cluster.
ds := DATASET('img.flat', myRec, THOR);
hex_data := Std.Str.ToHexPairs((>DATA<)ds.contents);
//d1:=Std.Str.FromHexPairs(hex_data);
// First output is just the file as we read it.
OUTPUT(ds[1]);
//OUTPUT(hex_data);
DATASET({UNSIGNED4 len, STRING filename, STRING img_bits, STRING img_byte}) pyProcess(STREAMED DATASET(myRec) recs) := EMBED(Python: Activity)
 import binascii
 for rec in recs:
   # Records come in as a tuple of fields
   name, dat = rec
   header = dat[:16]
   img_hex = binascii.hexlify(dat)
   img_bytes=binascii.unhexlify(img_hex)
 
   headerstr = ''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in header)
   # We yield one record at a time (as a tuple), or we could have
   # made a list and returned the whole list as one.  Using yield,
   # we can process as a stream, without having to load everythin
   # into memory at the same time.
   yield (len(dat), name, img_hex, img_bytes)


ENDEMBED;
// Second output is the results returned by python
OUTPUT(pyProcess(ds))
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just tested with this code:

```
IMPORT Std;
myRec := RECORD
  STRING filename;
  DATA contents;
END;
ds := DATASET([{'file1',D'123456ABCD'},{'file2',D'ABCD123456'}], myRec);
hex_data := Std.Str.ToHexPairs(ds[1].contents);
d1:=Std.Str.FromHexPairs(hex_data);
OUTPUT(ds);
OUTPUT(d1);
OUTPUT(hex_data);
```

You will note that my **hex_data** definition is different from yours, in two ways:

1. The type transfer operator (>DATA<) is unnecessary since the contents field is already defined as a DATA type.
2. I added the [1] reference to indicate the contents field from the first record, only. Without that, there would be a syntax error "no specified row for Table ds"

With those two changes, this code all runs correctly (including the d1 definition).
I suggest you incorporate those changes and see where you are then.'

HTH,

Richard

Comment: Thanks, it is working with hard coded STRINGS as in ur code.
But in my am trying to convert a BLOB sprayed image file to Bytes,

`ds := DATASET('img.flat', myRec, THOR);`

so is there any way I can convert the hex data returned by it as byte?

Comment: The image file can be processed by using a simple PROJECT.

ImgStream := PROJECT(ds,TRANSFORM({STRING hex_data},
                     SELF.hex_data := Std.Str.ToHexPairs(LEFT.contents)));
                                   
OUTPUT(ImgStream);